# EAR file needs to have a manifest with all jars?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ear

Why does it need to declare all JARs names inside the MANIFEST file when publishing a EAR ? The classpath shouldn't be enough?

Comment: Because the spec says so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an application in an EAR file, it is desireable that the application have its own classpath, independent of other applications on the server.  If the classpath for the server was used for all applications, that could force all of them to use the same versions of all jars they needed, which would be a maintenance nightmare.  If the application needs to use a set of jars that are specific to that application, the manifest file is the logical place to put them.

Comment: I was wrongly seeing an EAR aplication without thinking about the container, environment and its purpose. Tks for the answer.